# Running C# .NetCore with XUnit in Jenkins without the DLL

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, xunit

I recently took over a automation project that was written in .NetCore 3.1 using XUnit/Selenium. The Project that houses the code is a **console application**, not a class library so DLL of the tests are not created. I've had experience getting JAVA Maven based into Jenkins and running each tests a a standalone build in Jenkins but with this C# version, I am not sure how to proceed.
All of their automation is in one Project of the solution, broken down to cs files with a Class in each one hold all the FACT/THEORY Tests.
With .Net Framework, you can target the dll of each test to run it but in this case, I cannot see how to do this without the DLL. They essentially want to target the test Class in each file and run it as a build in Jenkins.

Is this even possible or do we need to convert it to a Class Library to get it to work in Jenkins? The company does NOT want to change it to a Class Library if that can be done.

I know that they will need to install MSTest and the plugin Active Choice Parameter to target their appsettings.json file as well.

Comment: Can't you just run the console app?

Comment: @GregBurghardt That is the question. I cannot find documentation on how to target specific tests within the Console Application using Jenkins without a DLL. They would like to target the XUnit Tests in the Project without DLL, just the CS file that contains them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` to your test project `.cproj` file

My example for net5.0
[image]